# Vue.js: Is there a way to make a buttons "v-if" reactive through watcher?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Basically, I have a userlist page with a bunch of other profiles including your own profile.
There is a button that only appears if you're on your own profile.

The problem is when I switch from some other profile to my own profile (Thus, paramater of the router is changing) that button should appear.
Vice-versa though works (my-profile -> another profile the button dissapears).

Now, the button only appears if I switch from another router (not from some other profile but instead a home page to my own profile for example).

#### On my Profile.vue

```
                        <v-btn
                            v-if= "isUserProfile()"
                            outline
                            large
                            fab
                            v-on="on"
                            color="indigo">
                        <v-icon>edit</v-icon>
                        </v-btn>
```

Using watcher in Profile.vue, looks out whenever the url/router param changes

```
  watch: {
        '$route.params.username': {
            immediate: true,
            handler (value) {
                this.username = value
                this.getId()
                this.isUserProfile()
            }
        }
    },
```

using the method,

```
isUserProfile () {
            return (this.$store.state.route.params.username === this.$store.state.user.username)
        },
```

So the button SHOULD appear everytime I switch to my own profile from another profile since it works when I switch from my profile to another profile.
For a gif example where my profile is "123123":

https://gyazo.com/cf47036bfb60cc6490c538e50a32db81

What I did here is switch the parameters on the url manually from going to my account, to another account back to my account.
(Button is there; good | is not there; good | button is still not there which should be there; bad.)

Comment: Why don't you make `isUserProfile` a computed value and use it in the `v-if` expression?

Comment: By setting `v-if= "isUserProfile()"`you're binding to the return value of the `isUserProfile()` function one single time when mounting the component.

Comment: by a computed value you mean  

computed: {
        isUserProfile: function () {
            return (this.$store.state.route.params.username === this.$store.state.user.username)
        }
    }

?

Comment: i did that, and also made a this.isUserProfileBool. still not affecting the v-if button reactivity

Comment: What happens if you put the following code somewhere in the layout: {{$store.state.route.params.username === $store.state.user.username}} - will it show true or false?

Comment: yea actually that's what i've been using to test. and it does actually update true and false whenver I change profiles. but it doesn't affect v-if or the button showing or not.

Comment: @tokibitsu are you 100% that this.$store.state.route.params.username === this.$store.state.user.username is not *true* all the time?

Comment: 110% sure, i can show you the result side by side right with this gif: https://gyazo.com/35bbd25edce6908788eb0772f55039da

(where the problem is the edit button doesn't show up/react if changed router/params on the same route page)

Comment: to add: for it to show up, the router must be of different routes i.e. home page -> profile and not profile->profile

Comment: @tokibitsu what you shown it's not exactly what I wanted you to do. I asked if you can put the expression somewhere right on the page (instead of doing it in debugger). Sorry if I got you wrong because the video is very small and I couldn't see everything well.

Comment: @Skipper, i've done what you asked and yes it can output the expression on the page but not just showing the button if v-if is true or false. https://gyazo.com/b895be9e6b3368256e042f26f10f48d2
(button still does not appear even if v-if is true)

Comment: Try: 1) remove isUserProfile from watch as for it's useless there 2) Remove brackets ( and ) from v-if: v-if="isUserProfile"

Comment: yea so currently right now I have updated it so that it's a computed value instead of watch, along with v-if: "isUserProfile" w/o brackets

Comment: @tokibitsu Hey, do you mean, it finally worked?

Comment: @Skipper, sadly after all those stuff it's still not working :(. im glad you're helping tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the answer is **simple** and the modifications of making it a computed value **was not necessary** as I just checked (I think it is better practice to make it computed value though).

**Answer**:
Instead of **v-if:isUserProfile**, make it **v-show:isUserProfile**; where now the button changes to how what is to be accomplished.

I will now be reading https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html for further knowledge.